# can't connect to azure rest web service

Tags: java, web-services, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to develop a client program that creates a device identity thanks to azure . im using azure rest to create it so i call this webservice from client programme using jersey implementation but i get error ***com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected: connect***
i test it using postman it work and python it work to .
here is my java code :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("https://xxxx-iot-hub.azure-devices.net/devices");

            ClientResponse response =     webResource.path("/iotdevice1").queryParam("top", "100").queryParam("api-version", "2016-02-03").header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", "SharedAccessSignature sr=xxxxx-iot-hub.azure-devices.net&sig=Yxxxxxxxxxx=1497357420&skn=iothubowner")
                    .put(ClientResponse.class);



            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Check your firewall configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, it seems that you want to create a new device identity using the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt548493.aspx) with HTTP PUT Method.

However, in your code, the query parameter `top=100` is not necessary and the request body `{deviceId: "iotdevice1"}` is missing.

Here is my working code.

```
String body = "{deviceId: \"iotdevices1\"}";
ClientResponse response = webResource.path("/iotdevices1").queryParam("api-version", "2016-02-03")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization",
                            "SharedAccessSignature sr=xxxx.azure-devices.net&sig=xxxxxxxx&se=1497357420&skn=iothubowner")
                    .put(ClientResponse.class, body);
```

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

---

**Update**:

For deleting a existing device identity, please see the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt548487.aspx) reference and see the code below.

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.path("/iotdevices1").queryParam("api-version", "2016-02-03")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("If-Match", "*")
                    .header("Authorization",
                            "SharedAccessSignature sr=xxxx.azure-devices.net&sig=xxxxxx&se=1497490976&skn=iothubowner")
                    .delete(ClientResponse.class);
```

Please take note of the header `If-Match` above.

Comment: Thank you it work ,can you please show me how to delete device using this rest api ?i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: @user3499324 I update the code for deleting device identity.